# ¿Podemos tener iconos en las etiquetas, como en SO?

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas

He visto en Stack Oveflow que en algunas etiquetas tienen iconos, como por ejemplo en [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) o [google-chrome](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome):

> [image: Iconos etiquetas SO]

¿Se podría implementar esa opción también Stack Overflow en español o seria una tontería e innecesario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se trata de etiquetas patrocinadas: la empresa en cuestión paga a Stack Overflow para que haya un estilo algo mejorado, así como mostrar anuncios en su página.

Puedes ver por ejemplo en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, entiendo que cambiarían de diseño si una empresa estuviera dispuesta a pagar por ello.

Si quieres leer más al respecto, mira [Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33081/209901)

> 1. Sponsored links and brand logo at the top of the "questions/tagged/[tagname]" page (below the navigation bar, but above the tag summary description)
> 2. Upper Leaderboard, Mid-Leaderboard and Sidebar static display ad inventory that associates with the questions that are tagged with the sponsored tag. (Note that users with a reputation over 200 don't see the leaderboard ads).
> 3. Brand logo on the `tag` itself throughout the site

Comment: la que que más cerca estuvo de tenerlo tuvo que ser [tag:mercadopago] hahah

Comment: mercadopago, toda una leyenda con la avalancha de preguntas que quedaron en el olvido por parte del "soporte de mercadopago"

Comment: Para mi gusto, lo de los iconos en las etiquetas se ve feo. Me gusta más SO en Español, las etiquetas sin más. No veo qué sentido tiene poner iconos ahí, me parece una exageración. Más aún si hay iconos para unas etiquetas y no para otras. Además se ve feo, hay etiquetas que ni siquiera se distinguen. La de Android mismo es un ejemplo de ello. Se ve horrible para mi gusto.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que la respuesta a _qué sentido tiene_ es fácil: dinero.

Comment: Si lo hacen por dinero más feo aún, y hasta vergonzoso e irrespetuoso para quienes *colaboramos* aquí sin ninguna intención lucrativa. Porque estaremos de acuerdo en que SO es lo que es por nosotros, ¿no?, por la calidad de lo que preguntamos/respondemos. Ellos tendrán que rentabilizarlo supongo para mantenimiento del sitio y demás, eso lo entiendo, pero que te inyecten publicidad hasta en las etiquetas me parece anti ético.

Comment: ¿Te imaginas que MercadoPago llegase a tener un logo en su etiqueta en SOes? A mi juicio es la etiqueta más fracasada del sitio en español, y el *estilo* que usaba (o que usa) su soporte técnico de ¿redirigir? las dudas de sus usuarios aquí era por lo menos cuestionable. Recuerdo hace poco que era cansino ver casi diario preguntas muy pobres sobre MercadoPago. Parece que algo se ha hecho porque ahora hay menos de esas preguntas. Pero que llegasen a tener su logo en una etiqueta... ufff

Comment: @A.Cedano no debemos olvidar que SO es una empresa y, por tanto, busca beneficios. Los anuncios en etiquetas es de las poquísimas cosas comerciales que ve un usuario con cierta reputación y no sé cuál sería la alternativa menos invasiva. Entiendo que estos patrocinios pasan por un filtro potente y no se le permite a cualquier empresa. El caso de MercadoPago fue bastante bestia, pero creo que más por dejadez de SOes en no contactar con la empresa y ponerse serios. No sé qué pasó después porque no vi info pública, pero me alegra lo que comentas que ahora hay menos de esas preguntas.